# Converting Blanks to 0 in Dax Causing date slicer to be ignored - Showing Null Values Outside of Date Range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to building a dashboard that has a date slicer synced to a line and stacked column chart and a matrix. The matrix has many zero values that appear as blank, but I want them to appear as 0 if they are not blank. Prior to changing my measure to have zeroes appear, the matrix functioned correctly in that it was in sync with the date slicer and the data corresponding to the date slicer. But now with this measure below...the matrix is now showing 0s beyond the date ranged selected in the date slicer (almost like a Null in SQL). How can I modify this Dax measure so that it has zeroes rather than blanks, but doesn't display false data beyond the date range selected?

NbrUnpaid =
IF (
CALCULATE([Count],Query1[Paid_Amount] = 0.00 ) = BLANK(),
0,
CALCULATE([Count],Query1[Paid_Amount] = 0.00 ) )

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your measure can probably be simplified to

```
[Count]+0
```

Secondly, you need to wrap your measure in the logic that prevents zero being returned outside of your date ranges. At the moment, you are telling PBI to return a value for every datapoint but you need to prevent that happening by finding the min date and max date of your fact and only returning values within that range.